# Pass Date Values from Ajax Call to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

MY Ajax call

```
 $('#QuickReserve').click(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        alert(now);

        var _data = {
            'ComputerName': _computerName,
            '_mStart': now.toTimeString(),
            '_mEnd': now.toDateString()
        };
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
//            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "/Home/SetMeeting",
            dataType: "json",
            data: _data,
            success: "",
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Error");
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

MY C# code

```
 public ActionResult SetMeeting(string ComputerName, DateTime? _mStart, DateTime? _mEnd)
        {
           }
```

DateTime values are not received at code end..... They just appear blank.
In jquery when i tried to

```
'_mStart': now.toTimeString(),
            '_mEnd': now.toDateString()
```

to datestring does return today's date, but, i want time part of date time also.

Comment: You should try to accept strings instead of datetime and then just parse the strings to dates after that. The issue is probably just a parsing issue

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Don't do any tricks with data formats. Just use standard function [date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) which returns in ISO8601 format.

from javascript

```
$.post('/example/do', { date: date.toISOString() }, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

from c#

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Do(DateTime date)
{
     return Json(date.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the marked answer is depend on the server's system date format.

Comment: Can't use this you want to receive the date from a datepicker. Any alternatives for when I want to receive a date from a datepicker?

Answer (score 12):

Converting the json date to this format    "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss"    is the whole trick
dateFormat is a function in jsondate format.js file found at 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

```
var _meetStartTime = dateFormat(now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just pass one DateTime up, and separate the Date part from the time part on the server?

Can you not just pass '_mDate': now;

```
public ActionResult SetMeeting(string ComputerName, DateTime? _mDate)
{
   // Then in here use _mDate.Date, and _mDate.Time    
}
```

Comment: Only date part is sent successfully, not the timepart

Comment: Can you not just pass '_mDate': now

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert the date (and time) into a timestamp from Unix Epoch and then use js to display the date?

c#

```
public double FromUnixEpoch(DateTime value)
{
    DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    double timeStamp = (value - unixEpoch).Ticks / 1000;
    return timeStamp;
}
```

js

```
var myDate = new Date( object.myEpochDate *1000);
myDate.toUTCString().toLocaleString();
```

With this approach you can pass the epoch as a string inside json and then handle it like a date in js.

Comment: I want to pass date from js to c#, and not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry Nikhil, misunderstood you. Is JS convert the datetime to unix epoch, var myDate= new Date(); var unixEpoch = myDate.getTime(); In C# convert it from unix epoch: public DateTime fromUnixEpoch(long epoch) { return (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(epoch); }

Comment: I came up with an easy solution, i formatted the json date to the "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss" format, and it worled like magic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with formatting. You can definitely use libs or plugins, I chose to keep it really simple:

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var curr_date = date.getDate();
  var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
  return curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;          
}
```

KISS!