# Kendo calendar: How can I send date to controller on change event? ( MVC Extensions )

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I did make the following example, but is not working :

Controller Home:

```
namespace KendoUIMvcApplication1.Controllers
{
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
          public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date)
          {
             //here i use the date bla bla bla

               return View();
          }

          public ActionResult About()
          {
               return View();
          }
     }
}
```

My view : Index.cshtml

```
<p>
    @Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("Calendario").Value(DateTime.Now).Events(e =>e.Change("change"))
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        var dado = this.value();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index", //url
            traditional: false,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            data: dado,
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("erro");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Why when I change the date on the calendar, the param is null on the controller?
The function $Ajax is working fine; the var dado has a date.

Comment: Please edit the question and post if you get any error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to to send the value as Key/Value pair object.
e.g.

```
data: {date:dado},
```

Also you might need to format the date into a convenient for the ModelBInder format

e.g.

```
data:{date:kendo.format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",dado)}
```

Comment: Okey then the format is wrong try to send the value like I edited my answer

Comment: tks again but dont work. I tried to send a simple string on data, changing the parameter on action, but dont work too.

Comment: I do not see any difference compared to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076961/pass-date-values-from-ajax-call-to-mvc except the 'tt' part at the end of the formatting.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, its worked. Works fine if you use: data: {
                data: kendo.toString(dado, "d") too.  thank you very much @Petur-Subev